Sketch comedy about the British class system
Sometime in the 1990s (just maybe the 1980s) I saw one episode of a sketch comedy show that I was not familiar with and it has stuck in my head ever since.
The episode was concerned with notion of class in British society. Two sketches stick out in my memory:

A short sketch set on a train or plane (rows of seating) in which a couple is arguing with a steward over their placement.  

You put us in upper-middle-middle, but we  belong in lower-upper-middle.

And the steward is quizzing them about their house, cars and occupations to check their claim. When he asks about the wife's work the husband replies  

Trick question! Nothing but a little charity work.

An extended sequence involving a the daughter of a working class couple sent to an expensive boarding school. In the last sequence they actually visit the school where the daughter hustles them into a closet for a brief discussion of why that can't be seen around her, then shoos them off explaining to her friends that they were applicants for the custodial job opening.  
As the aged parents totter away, they discuss the visit  

She just spat on everything we stand for.
Yes. It's everything we every hoped.

Fade to black on their contented smiles.


I am not a regular viewer of sketch comedy, so the only show I feel confident to rule out is Monty Python.

You're looking for the 1993 special Tracey Ullman: A Class Act. Both sketches are on Wiki:


The show opens aboard "Class Air", a British airline that seats passengers according to social class: lower, middle, upper. Airline steward, Trevor Ayliss, explains to an American passenger the seating arrangement.
Young girl Janie Pillsworth is put into a posh school by her working class parents. Her mother and father give up all their possessions in order to afford tuition, including her father who sells a kidney. Janie, who's now turned posh, disowns her parents, making them promise to never speak to her again. Despite Janie's contempt, Mr. and Mrs. Pillsworth cannot be happier since Janie has become exactly what they wanted her to be.


Here's the extended airplane sketch:



